# Regarding linking CLI Parser to my application

Tags: c, command-line-interface

I am using an open source CLI parser (this one -> http://sourceforge.net/projects/cliparser/) to add command line interface to my application and it works really neat on its own, but I am having trouble adding it to my application. The documentation provided is very meager and I have limited experience with makefiles. If anyone has used this parser before could you help me out with it?

Specifically, how do I make the parser run within my program? The document says"link your parser against libparser.a" What does that mean?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a `Makefile`? Please post it as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compile your program, you need to link against the library.  If using GCC, this is done via two ways:

1. You can specify the path to the library:

   ```
   gcc myapp.c /somepath/libparser.a
   ```
2. Or, if it is in your standard library directory you should be able to do:

   ```
   gcc myapp.c -l parser
   ```